# Using "I" first

Tags: word-choice

I have a friend that says "I and John went to the store"  instead of "John and I went to the store".   Is this still correct?

Comment: This has been asked, and answered, [quite a few times before](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/1133?lq=1). Please search the site before asking. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

No, the convention is to put it in the following order:

```
John and I went to the store.
```

If adding a second person pronoun it goes between:

```
John, you and I went to the store.
```

Third person first, second person second, first person last.